# Pandas read csv with negative lookahead as seperator

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I´m trying to read a csv file with the help of pandas.

The file contains rows which look like:
10, 5, 1, [12, 5], [14, 7]

The csv file should contain 5 colums for the example above

1. 10
2. 5
3. 1
4. [12, 5]
5. [14, 7]

I know that you can use regex for the seperator and I tried to solve my problem with the help of negative lookahead. For example: `[,](?!(.+)?\])` The aim is to look for a comma which is not followed by a "]".

But with the regex above it does not work! Whats wrong with the expression? Or is there an easier way to seperate the columns?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps, [`,(?![^][]*])`](https://regex101.com/r/SeBOFn/2) or [`\s*,(?![^][]*])\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/SeBOFn/3) will work.

Comment: Unfortunately no :( When I print out the data frame all the values are in the first column

Comment: Yes the second solutions works ! Thank you very much !:)

Comment: `,(?![^,\]]*\])` is less complicated, no?

Comment: @usr2564301 [That pattern](https://regex101.com/r/hzkSnc/1) will still match commas inside `[...]` if there are more than one.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: true (but the data doesn't contain that as example ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your regex contains the `(?!(.+)?\])` negative lookahead that returns true even if there is a `]` after any `[` and `]` because `.` can match these brackets. You need to make sure there is no `]` after any chars other than `[` and `]`. Also, to remove the whitespaces around `,` you need to add `\s*` round it.

Use

```
\s*,(?![^][]*])\s*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JFzLEi/1).

**Details**

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `,` - a `,` char (no need to put it into a character class)
- `(?![^][]*])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, the following pattern matches:

  - `[^][]*` - any 0+ chars other than `]` and `[`
  - `]`  - a `]` char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars

Comment: When it comes to regex I´m always struggeling. But what you said make sense. Thanks for the solution & explanaition!